# Julia loop with variable bound gives "invalid index"

Tags: julia

In julia when I do:

```
N=1000;
for i = 2:N,
    alpham[i] = 0.1 * (V[i-1]+40.) / (1. - exp(-(V[i-1]+40.)/10.));
end
```

with alpham and V vectors of lenght 1000. I get the error "ArgumentError: invalid index: 1.0". However, if I do:

```
for i = 2:1000,
```

it does work. Is there any reason why the previous one doesn't or is there any way I can still use N in my for loop? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Xentro

Comment: Are you sure it is not `N=1000.;` ?

Comment: I don't explicitly use N=1000 it's N=floor(...); that should cast it as int right?

Comment: Nope - you need `N = floor(Int,...)` to get an Int. You can't index with a Float.

Comment: BTW you should post an MWE (minimal working example) (including e.g. `alpham, V = ones(1000), ones(1000)` so that people can copy-paste the code, and you should run the MWE before posting it to ensure it reproduces the error. In this case your MWE actually runs with no problem.

Comment: 2 minor comments: 1) you don't need to end statements with `;` it just clutters the code. 2) don't put a `,` after `for i = 2:1000`.

Comment: removing the comma fixed it, thanks a lot. I thought you needed ; to suppress output. I'm used to coding in C++ anyway. PS: sorry for not including a MWE but I got a large code body it was hard to find all relevant lines, I just knew N was 1k but it's defined somewhere at the top

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard please repost your comment as an answer so it can be marked as solved, thanks!

Comment: Done (15 chars)

Answer (score 12):

The ArgumentError tells you that you're indexing with a `Float64`, doing that isn't defined in Julia. In your Minimally Working Example (MWE) you initialize `N` as 1000 (an `Int`) so the MWE actually doesn't reproduce the error, but in your comment you note that in your original code you get N as `floor(x)`, which returns a float. To get an `Int` you need `floor(Int, x)`.

There are also some syntax issues: you shouldn't have a `,` after `for i = 2:1000`, and it is usually not necessary to end statements with `;`.

Note that you should make sure that the MWE can run purely by copy-pasting the code in a REPL (i.e. so variables need to be initialized, `alpham, V = ones(1000), ones(1000)`). Run it yourself before posting to ensure it reproduces the error you report, and to catch any syntax errors.

Comment: @Xentro It is also not good style to use `40.` etc. as a literal. The dot `.` plays an important part in much Julia code, so can be potentially confusing or even cause errors. `3.+4` is different from `3. +4`. Use `40.0` instead, it's just more readable. In fact, you are probably better of just using integer literals in your case, `exp(-(V[i-1]+40)/10)` gets type-promoted to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that note. That part I actually copy-pasted from my professor.